# How can i import json object using android volley?

Tags: php, android, json, android-volley

I'm following this [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) to import [json data](https://mohamedslama.000webhostapp.com/connect.php) from online server.
fortunately that's work when i request as [`StringRequest`](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html),
but unfortunately not working when request as [`JsonObjectRequest`](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html)
fail in volley exception :

> 08-27 18:14:24.586 32344-32344/com.mohamedslama.trydb E/TAG:
>   com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value connected
>   of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

and here is the [`php file`](https://pastebin.com/YyQ2p2hx) .

so any suggestion please,
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need this function -> header("Content-type:application/json");
To inform Volley that server send json data

Comment: @MilosLulic i'm sorry i posted the old php code , i fixed the url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `echo "connected"` from line 8 in your php code.
It destroy the json structure

Comment: wow that's awesome , i think it's a silly fault string then another string that's make scenes , thank you